# JS three file inputs form code simplification

Tags: javascript, forms, input, label

I have a form with three file inputs. Those inputs are hidden with css because I wanted to customize them, so they're represented by their labels.

I have a working solution that attaches a file name and file size to it's label when file is choosed but it repeats same code three times.

I've tried so many for loop / for/for loop solutions but didn't achieved same functionality.

Can anyone help with a solution that doesn't repeats same code three times?

```
const file1 = document.querySelector('#file_1');

file1.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    // Get the selected file
    const [file] = e.target.files;
    // Get the file name and size
    const { name: fileName, size } = file;
    // Convert size in bytes to kilo bytes
    const fileSize = (size / 1000).toFixed(2);
    // Set the text content
    const fileNameAndSize = `${fileName} - ${fileSize}KB`;
    document.querySelector('.file1-name').textContent = fileNameAndSize;
});

const file2 = document.querySelector('#file_2');

file2.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    // Get the selected file
    const [file] = e.target.files;
    // Get the file name and size
    const { name: fileName, size } = file;
    // Convert size in bytes to kilo bytes
    const fileSize = (size / 1000).toFixed(2);
    // Set the text content
    const fileNameAndSize = `${fileName} - ${fileSize}KB`;
    document.querySelector('.file2-name').textContent = fileNameAndSize;
});

const file3 = document.querySelector('#file_3');

file3.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    // Get the selected file
    const [file] = e.target.files;
    // Get the file name and size
    const { name: fileName, size } = file;
    // Convert size in bytes to kilo bytes
    const fileSize = (size / 1000).toFixed(2);
    // Set the text content
    const fileNameAndSize = `${fileName} - ${fileSize}KB`;
    document.querySelector('.file3-name').textContent = fileNameAndSize;
});
```

Comment: `function validateFile (e.target, '.file1-name') {}` <= and put the non-dynamic parts in the method.  Call said method

Answer (score 0):

This snippet below does what you want while keeping the code exactly the same.

```js
for (const i of [1,2,3]) {
    const file = document.querySelector(`#file_${i}`);
    file.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        // Get the selected file
        const [file] = e.target.files;
        // Get the file name and size
        const { name: fileName, size } = file;
        // Convert size in bytes to kilo bytes
        const fileSize = (size / 1000).toFixed(2);
        // Set the text content
        const fileNameAndSize = `${fileName} - ${fileSize}KB`;
        document.querySelector(`.file${i}-name`).textContent = fileNameAndSize;
    });
}
```

A better approach would be to reuse the same `onChange` handler. You need to know which `'.fileN-name'` element goes with which form input. One way to achieve that would be to use an HTML5 data attribute so you could then read it in the event handler as `e.target.dataSet.[YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME_HERE]`. This would require changing the HTML though.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I've only had to add $ before i variable `#file_{i}` => `#file_${i}`.